# Get element's CSS selector (when it doesn't have an id)

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

I'm trying to modify a page through JavaScript/CSS (much like Stylish or Greasemonkey do). This is a very complex page (that I didn't build, or can't modify pre-render), which makes constructing the CSS selector hard to do (manually looking at document structure). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, but how *can* you identify the element? Or do you mean build full DOM tree?

Comment: my final intent is to create a css selector for the object. i can look at the pages code and deduct this path by looking at the document (sample selector from gmail.com "div.nH.T4.pp + div.pp + div.nH.pp.ps.TZ"), i'd like a way to help me build the selector.

Comment: Hey rcphq did u find any solution for this problem I am also searching for same thing.

Comment: Why not either use it's id if it has one, or just assign it a new id if it does not have one?

Comment: This is a more complex problem than it seems and there are [good libraries that solve it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068272/getting-a-jquery-selector-for-an-element/32218234#32218234). Also, it's a duplicate of [Getting a jQuery selector for an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068272/getting-a-jquery-selector-for-an-element).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use FireFox with FireBug installed.

- Right-click any element
- Select "Inspect Element"
- Right click the element in the HTML tree
- Select "Copy XPath" or "Copy CSS Path"

Output for the permalink to this answer (XPath):

> /html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/a

CSS Path:

> html body.question-page div.container div#content div#mainbar div#answers div#answer-4588287.answer table tbody tr td table.fw tbody tr td.vt div.post-menu a

---

But regarding this comment:

> my final intent is to create a css
>   selector for the object ...

If that is your intent, there may be an easier way through JavaScript:

```
var uniquePrefix = 'isThisUniqueEnough_';
var counterIndex = 0;
function addCssToElement(elem, cssText){
    var domId;
    if(elem.id)domId=elem.id;
    else{
        domId = uniquePrefix + (++counterIndex);
        elem.id = domId;
    }
    document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("#"+domId+"{"+cssText+"}");
}
```

The last line may need to be implemented differently for different browsers. Did not test.

Comment: Thanks, i was using chrome's version of firebug (lite) and couldn't find this option. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 68):

```
function fullPath(el){
  var names = [];
  while (el.parentNode){
    if (el.id){
      names.unshift('#'+el.id);
      break;
    }else{
      if (el==el.ownerDocument.documentElement) names.unshift(el.tagName);
      else{
        for (var c=1,e=el;e.previousElementSibling;e=e.previousElementSibling,c++);
        names.unshift(el.tagName+":nth-child("+c+")");
      }
      el=el.parentNode;
    }
  }
  return names.join(" > ");
}

console.log(  fullPath( $('input')[0] ) );
// "#search > DIV:nth-child(1) > INPUT:nth-child(1)"
```

This seems to be what you are asking for<strike>, but you may realize that this is not guaranteed to uniquely identify only one element. (For the above example, all the sibling inputs would be matched as well.)</strike>

**Edit**: Changed code to use `nth-child` instead of CSS classes to properly disambiguate for a single child.

Comment: nice succinct pure js function :) Just a slight note that the :nth-child wont work when applied to the HTML tag... or at least I can't get it to work in Firefox or Chrome... I guess it's probably due to the fact that <html> has no parent.

Comment: no problem, it's not something I would have thought about either :) I've submitted a subtle edit changing "HTML" to "html" in your new revision... due to the .toLowerCase() method.

Comment: Note that since CSS selectors do not allow selecting DOM text nodes, this code will produce wrong result in such case (el.tagName will give undefined).

Comment: Not bad... might want to package it into a library, or maybe improve [one](https://github.com/fczbkk/css-selector-generator) of the [10+ ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068272/getting-a-jquery-selector-for-an-element/32218234#32218234) that do the same thing.

Comment: This will work nicely until they prepend another child, which is the inherent problem with `nth-child()` selectors. I would derive a selector using specificity instead.

Comment: Thanks, for the code. My two cents: if you're using a newer javascript version you will want to use 'let' instead of 'var'. In this case, you will have to add 'let c, e;' *before* the 'for', and *remove* the 'var' within the 'for'. If you don't do this, 'c' will be 'undefined' in the line *after* the 'for'. See why at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/2457251

Answer (score 22):

I found I could actually use [this code from chrome devtools source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/devtools/front_end/components/DOMPresentationUtils.js) to solve this, without that many modifications.

After adding relevant methods from `WebInspector.DOMPresentationUtils` to new namespace, and fixing some differences, I simply call it like so:

```
> UTILS.cssPath(node)
```

*For implementation example* [see `css_path.js`](https://gist.github.com/asfaltboy/8aea7435b888164e8563)

Comment: This is by far the best solution I have found. I published it on npm for convenience: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cssman

Comment: @Macks: might you be willing to [publish the source on GitHub](https://github.com/maximilianschmitt/iniquest/issues/1)?

Comment: Actually the [Chromium code produces a lot of non-unique selectors](https://github.com/fczbkk/css-selector-generator-benchmark/blob/master/README.md#chromiums-dompresentationutils).

Comment: If by non unique you mean the produced selector should return 1 and only 1 element, it was never explicitly asked for by op. But should be fairly easy to modify code to check for siblings and get index or other distinct attribute

Comment: Why would it produce non-uniques? I thought it did n-th child things?

Answer (score 6):

Check this CSS selector generator library [@medv/finder](https://github.com/antonmedv/finder)

- Generates shortest selectors
- Unique selectors per page
- Stable and robust selectors
- 2.9 kB gzip and minify size

Example of generated selector:

```
.blog > article:nth-child(3) .add-comment
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
function getCssSelector(el)
{
    names = [];
    do {
        index = 0;
        var cursorElement = el;
        while (cursorElement !== null)
        {
            ++index;
            cursorElement = cursorElement.previousElementSibling;
        };
        names.unshift(el.tagName + ":nth-child(" + index + ")");
        el = el.parentElement;
    } while (el !== null);

    return names.join(" > ");
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts on why it doesn't work in Safari?

Answer (score 0):

you can use for css first-child pseudo classes if the element is a first child in a div table or body..etc

you can use jquery's nth child() function.

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

example from jquery.com

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>

  div { float:left; }
  span { color:blue; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div><ul>
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Karl</li>
    <li>Brandon</li>

  </ul></div>
  <div><ul>
    <li>Sam</li>
  </ul></div>

  <div><ul>
    <li>Glen</li>
    <li>Tane</li>
    <li>Ralph</li>

    <li>David</li>
  </ul></div>
<script>$("ul li:nth-child(2)").append("<span> - 2nd!</span>");</script>

</body>
</html>
```

my 2 cents if I understood the question correctly.

Comment: this would work, but im doing this on a page i didnt build so id need to somehow get what "nth-child" it is. this is my main problem.