# protractor plugin: Html parsing lib to locate element on the page?

Tags: html, xpath, protractor, html-parsing, node-modules

I am looking for protractor plugin, which parses HTML page looking for a particular string and gives me element selector?

For example, parse html files, search for occurrences of a particular string and then generate the element & xpath expressions that locate the string within the html file. Is there a node module which can automate this? or help me achieve this?

I want to use this in my protractor tests.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*Choosing a good selector for an element is not something you can easily automate.*

Tools like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) can generate XPath expressions and CSS selectors for selected elements, but they are either absolute and start from the very root `html` element, or can usually be simplified or improved.

Making a selector and a good one requires knowledge about what the structure of a particular page, the uniqueness of element's attributes and strategic thinking (using things that have less chances to change over time). `id`s, `class`es and other *data-oriented* attributes are usually good choices to rely on.

Look into [`elementor` package](https://github.com/andresdominguez/elementor) - it makes debugging locators easy and convenient.

Also see:

- [Get element's CSS selector (when it doesn't have an id)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588119/get-elements-css-selector-when-it-doesnt-have-an-id)