# Inspector-style string representation of DOM node

Tags: javascript, dom

With JavaScript, how can I get a string representation of a DOM node similar to what the Chrome and WebKit inspectors display?

```css
tag#id.class1.class2
```

A real example would look something like these:

```css
div#top-menu.feature.active
li.#callout.product
```

The desired strings might be query selectors, but I haven't found a native way of extracting them. These don't need to be absolutely precise CSS selectors either (no `nth-child`, etc.), just an identifying query string.

Comment: This might be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4588211/2991739

Comment: @Matías I saw that, thank you. This wouldn't be difficult to write, but was hoping there was an attribute or built-in function to return the string. It's clearly already built into Chrome and Safari.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a built-in function for this. You should implement it.