# Python Selenium - Check if a WebElement is equal to another WebElement

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, getattribute

How to compare two selenium WebElements to see if they are the same ?

First I retrieve a list of `input_fields` and the `first_input` element:

`self.input_fields = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, class_name)`
`self.first_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, id)`

Then I try to check if `input_fields[0]` and `first_input` are the same WebElement.

```
if self.first_input is not self.input_fields[0]:
    self.__log.warning("WebElement first_input : {} != {}".format(self.first_input, self.input_fields[0]))
```

Though the `session` and `element` are the same, the warning message is in any case triggered.

```
WARNING  - WebElement first_input: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="796bf0bcf3e0df528ee932d477951689", element="94a2ee62-9511-45e5-8aa3-bd3d3e9be309")> != <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="796bf0bcf3e0df528ee932d477951689", element="94a2ee62-9511-45e5-8aa3-bd3d3e9be309")>
```

Comment: Seems like you are trying compare two web elements. You can't compare two web-elements.If you wish to compare the inputs tag then compare their attribute or text value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit:
the use of `!=` instead of `is not` would have resolved everything:

```
if self.first_input != self.input_fields[0]:
```

### Solution

```
if self.first_input.id == self.input_fields[0].id:
    self.__log.info("Same element {} , {}".format(self.first_input.id, self.input_fields[0].id))
```

Reading the docs I've found the [**id**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.id) property, whose [definition](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.html#WebElement.id) serves as getter for the private attribute`_id`

```
@property
def id(self):
    """Internal ID used by selenium.

    This is mainly for internal use. Simple use cases such as checking if 2
    webelements refer to the same element, can be done using ``==``::

        if element1 == element2:
            print("These 2 are equal")

    """
    return self._id
```

[source](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.html#WebElement)

```
class WebElement(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, id_, w3c=False):
        self._parent = parent
        self._id = id_
        self._w3c = w3c
```

---

Note:

```
print("{}".format(self.first_input.id))
```

Gives us the element id which is the same that we have seen in the object.

```
94a2ee62-9511-45e5-8aa3-bd3d3e9be309
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare WebElements should work, print **id** of `first_element` and `input_fields[0]` to check. Also, print all **ids** of `input_fields` to check if there are any duplicate elements with the same id.

As an option you can try to compare the full CSS path of the two elements, [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588119/get-elements-css-selector-when-it-doesnt-have-an-id).

```
script = """
function fullPath(element){
  var names = [];
  while (element.parentNode) {
      if (element==element.ownerDocument.documentElement) names.unshift(element.tagName);
      else{
        for (var i=1, e=element; e.previousElementSibling; e=e.previousElementSibling,i++);
        names.unshift(element.tagName+":nth-child("+i+")");
      }
      element=element.parentNode;
  }
  return names.join(" > ");
}
return fullPath(arguments[0]);
"""

first_input_full_path = driver.execute_script(script, self.first_input)
another_input_full_path = driver.execute_script(script, self.input_fields[0])

if first_input_full_path == another_input_full_path:
    self.__log.warning("WebElement first_input : {} != {}".format(self.first_input, self.input_fields[0]))
```