# How to find XPath of an element using Selenium Driver in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get absolute XPath of an element but in Google I can find results only to get element from XPath.

```
IWebElement webElement = (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript("return document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1])", windowPoint.x, windowPoint.y);
```

I can see some of the answers [Want to Retrieve Xpath of Given WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069382/want-to-retrieve-xpath-of-given-webelement) for Java.

Can we get XPath details of an element using C# code?

Comment: What do you mean? _I am trying to get absolute XPath of an element_ - You can not do that programmatically, obviously there's no need as well.

Comment: @cruisepandey - In my question, I've given link with Java example. I need similar solution for C#.Net.

Comment: You can use the one from the java example. Just modify it to c#.   public static string GetAbsoluteXPath(IWebElement element)
        {
            return (string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript( /// extra code );

Comment: I think the bigger question is *why* you need the absolute xpath. That is the problem you need to solve.

Comment: @GregBurghardt - I need absolute XPath details for automation purpose.

Comment: @GregBurghardt - Can you please share the link here if the answer is already available.

Comment: I don't have the answer because you haven't asked the question. Can you tell us why you need the absolute xpath? There might be a better solution to your problem.

Comment: IWebElement webElement => Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li/a"]")); is how we define th e XPath in selenium with C# if you say yes I can provide you with a complete answer.