# Selenium and XPath in Python: Get the Xpath of an element I found with find_element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I wrote a python script to get data from a webpage. I used selenium and the script ran fine until the provider of the homepage changed it. I found that the Xpaths of the elements I looked for changed and I am now eager to find a solution to get my code to find xpaths dynamically whenever the path changes. So here the current status:

```
a=web.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="grid"]/div[111]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/input')
```

after the provider updated the homepage:

`b=web.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="grid"]/div[333]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/input')`

Now I can get the element by using the following:

```
c=web.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(), 'SoAndSo')]")
```

Now does anyone know a way I can use to get the full `Xpath` of `c`? From `a` to `b`, there was one change from 111 to 333. My idea is to find the element `c` and than extract the number (333 in this case) and continue from there. I read multiple tutorials to selenium but my problem seems to be too outlandish (or easy). So any advice is appreciated.

I tried different ways of finding the `xpath`, stripping the homepage source code, alternating ways in finding element...

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47088726/3710053