# Python Selenium Element - Get xPath and/or CSS Selector from element (not find element by)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, element

I want to get the xpath & css_selector of an element. Is there a property of the element that I can use?

Please note, I am not trying to find the an element by xpath or css selector. I already have the element, I want to know what its xpath / css_selector is.

Many thanks

I have read the documentation here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html... and could not find the answer.

Comment: https://qxf2.com/blog/auto-generate-xpaths-using-python/

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible. you may write your own function to implement that, but there's no built-in methods. check approaches here [Find an element by text and get xpath - selenium webdriver junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510576/find-an-element-by-text-and-get-xpath-selenium-webdriver-junit)